# Adding a SUM() expression causes my Access query to stop working

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I am getting following error for a Select Query after adding `SUM(b.[Amount_withDiscount])` and `inner join on tables` to a query that was previously working. Now I want the query to also return the sum of that column in the related table. Where have I gone wrong?

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'p.[PFirstName] & ' ' & p.[PLastName]' as part of an aggregate function.

**working Query**

```
string sql = "SELECT p.[PFirstName]&' '&p.[PLastName] as [Patient Name],p.[Age],p.[BirthDate],p.[MobileNo]&' / '&p.[LandlineNo] as [Contact Number] FROM Patient_Registration p WHERE datepart('m',p.[RegDate])=@month AND datepart('yyyy',p.[RegDate])=@year AND p.DoctorID=" + drId;
```

**Query after adding sum and inner join**

```
string sql = "SELECT p.[PFirstName]&' '&p.[PLastName] as [Patient Name],p.[Age],p.[BirthDate],p.[MobileNo]&' / '&p.[LandlineNo] as [Contact Number], SUM(b.[Amount_withDiscount]) as [Payable Amount] FROM Patient_Registration p INNER JOIN Bill_Master b on p.[PatientID]=b.[Patient_ID] WHERE datepart('m',p.[RegDate])=@month AND datepart('yyyy',p.[RegDate])=@year AND p.DoctorID=" + drId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you added the `SUM()` expression you changed the query from a regular Select Query into an Aggregation Query that expects each output field to be either

- part of an aggregate function (`SUM()`, `MAX()`, etc.), or
- included in the GROUP BY clause (which is not present in your query).

In this case, for just one sum, you'd probably be better off using `DSum()` instead of `SUM()`, as in

```
string sql = "SELECT p.[PFirstName]&' '&p.[PLastName] as [Patient Name],p.[Age],p.[BirthDate],p.[MobileNo]&' / '&p.[LandlineNo] as [Contact Number], DSum(\"Amount_withDiscount\",\"Bill_Master\",\"Patient_ID=\" & p.[PatientID]) as [Payable Amount] FROM Patient_Registration p WHERE datepart('m',p.[RegDate])=@month AND datepart('yyyy',p.[RegDate])=@year AND p.DoctorID=" + drId;
```

Comment: And How Do i write Inner Join in this query than ?

Comment: @Durga If you use `DSum()` then you don't need to do a join in the main query. `DSum()` is a Domain Aggregate function that performs its own subquery. For more information on `DSum()` look [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/dsum-function-HA001228829.aspx).

Comment: Yes you Are right ,Thank You :),Can you Please tell me one more thing `Dsum` Will be in what dataType formate I mean int or decimal? Because its showing me `DataType Mismatch`

Comment: getting this error `<target>.Payable Amount and <source>.Payable Amount have conflicting properties: DataType property mismatch.` In DataSet I have set this column as `INT32` I tried setting it with `Decimal` also

Comment: @Durga `DSum()` should either return a value that is the same type as the column [Amount_withDiscount], or `DBNull.Value` if no matching records were found.

Comment: column [Amount_withDiscount] is Of `Number` DataType in Access ,and hence in dataset I set it to `Int32` ,am I wrong Here ? its giving me error

Comment: @Durga In Access, when the `Data Type` is `Number` the `Field Size` can be `Long Integer`, `Double`, or one of several other subtypes. Which is it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39644/discussion-between-durga-and-gord-thompson)